# create pojo service interface from wsdl

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-axis, jibx

I need to create a POJO service interface from a wsdl .
I tried Axis and CXF. 
CXF generates the interface with jax-ws annotations. 
Axis , I believe has a different strategy for web service client and I could not find the service interface.

Let me know if you have tried any such requirement before.

Answer (score 0):

Lives,

I noticed that you added a jibx tag. You might want to look at the JiBX CXF web service examples:

SOAP:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/webservice.html

REST:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/rest.html

Cheers!

Don